# Flyway migrate Oracle PL/SQL dump

Tags: flyway

Flyway offers a oracle pl/sql parser, so is it possible using a pl/sql dump (.pde) for a migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dump must be in .sql format. Binary exports are not supported.